# Start a Maridb service in GitLab CI failed

Tags: docker, gitlab, mariadb

I tried to add a mariadb service in GitLab CI for running tests.

Define the docker vars in gobal `variables` and add a `mariadb` in the job test/services.

```yaml
variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: backend
  MYSQL_USER: admin
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin

test:
  stage: test
  image: maven:3.6.3-openjdk-16
  services:
    - name: mariadb
      alias: db
      command: [ "--character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci" ]
  ...
```

When the codes are pushed to GitLab.com.

And I saw the following logs.

```sh
Starting service mariadb:latest ...
Pulling docker image mariadb:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:e76a4b2ed1b4014a9d638e15cd852544d8171c64ed78096fbe6e5a108fbf20b0 for mariadb:latest with digest mariadb@sha256:9c681cefe72e257c6d58f839bb504f50bf259a0221c883fcc220f0755563fa46 ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
*** WARNING: Service runner-fa6cab46-project-18612327-concurrent-0-0fddafc5b30beaaa-mariadb-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
start service container: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /runner-fa6cab46-project-18612327-concurrent-0-0fddafc5b30beaaa-mariadb-0 AS /runner-fa6cab46-project-18612327-concurrent-0-0fddafc5b30beaaa-mariadb-0-wait-for-service/service (docker.go:1156:0s)
Service container logs:
2021-04-13T08:30:50.821859467Z 2021-04-13 08:30:50+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.9+maria~focal started.
2021-04-13T08:30:50.920686916Z 2021-04-13 08:30:50+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: mysqld failed while attempting to check config
2021-04-13T08:30:50.920714063Z  command was: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci --verbose --help --log-bin-index=/tmp/tmp.Kzx9BNn0Bl --encrypt-tmp-files=0
2021-04-13T08:30:50.920720617Z  mysqld: Character set 'utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file
2021-04-13T08:30:50.920875405Z mysqld: Character set 'utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file
```

But I ran a mariadb instance in my docker container, it is working well, not seen such info.

Comment: `command:` is a list, quote and comma separate the two options.

Comment: Splitting to two parameters, no help.

Comment: I can see no way after splitting that the error message would be the same.

Comment: @danblack maybe it is timeout errors. When moving the `services` to the top level, the error is missing.